# Vertical writing/drawing not working in web view

Tags: javascript, android, xamarin, signaturepad

I am using [szimek signature_pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/) in the web-view of xamarin app. I am able to draw lines or write horizontally but they don't seem to be working vertically.

Everything works fine in Desktop and Mobile Google chrome browser and signatures work perfect but when I use the same link inside web-view, only dots appear when I try to write vertically. I doubt that may be caused by web-view vertical scroll but cant figure out how to solve this.

[image: issue]

Comment: can you please share your layout code please? I have faced similar problem, it was happening because of a vertical scroll view on top of the WebView that was preventing vertical strokes inside the WebView. I just removed that vertical scroll view and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Specific scroll view in your layout file. Parent view of your WebView must be other than scroll view otherwise when you try to draw a vertical line your layout try to scroll your view vertically and gets the focus and that action conflict with your vertical stroke. If you still want to use scroll view your web view must be outside that scroll view